# Specify private key in SSH as string

Tags: bash, ssh

I can connect to a server via SSH using the -i option to specify the private key:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_dsa user@hostname
```

I am creating a script that takes the `id_dsa` text from the database but I am not sure how I can give that string to SSH. I would need something like:

```
ssh --option $STRING user@hostname
```

Where `$STRING` contains the value of `id_dsa`. I need to know the `--option` if there is one.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Is this relevant for the question? I am using OSX and Linux

Comment: Only reason I asked was to give specific advice on creating temp files. But the info given by @Kimvais is sufficient.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46253162

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no such switch - as it would leak sensitive information. If there were, *anyone* could get your *private* key by doing a simple `ps` command.

**EDIT**: (because of theg added details in comment)

You really should store the key in to a temporary file. Make sure you set the permissions correctly before writing to the file, if you do not use command like `mktemp` to create the temporary file.

<strike>Make sure you run the broker (or agent in case of OpenSSH) process and load the key using `<whatever command you use to fetch it form the database> | ssh-add -`</strike>

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your second paragraph. I do not want any agent involved. I am using ssh shell command in a Ruby application, where I have an infrastructure with associated a public and private key. With the private key, taken from the record of the infrastructure, I want to connect and run a command on a remote host . That's why I want to keep the private key in the record of the infrastructure. But probably is better to store the path of a file and pass the path to ssh command.

Comment: @rtacconi You could implement the [ssh-agent protocol](http://api.libssh.org/rfc/PROTOCOL.agent).

Comment: @kimvais I checked in the man ssh and I cannot see any option to use a string instead of a file.

Comment: I disagree with this sentiment.  I'd argue that transient data is always more secure than permanent data.  With the right tools most deleted files can still be read.  I'm looking for a solution which receives keys from a server and utilizes them on the fly as part of a CI process.  Perhaps a shell is the wrong tool for this?

Answer (score 51):

Try the following:

```
echo $KEY | ssh -i /dev/stdin username@host command
```

The key doesn't appear from a PS statement, but because stdin is redirected it's only useful for single commands or tunnels.

Comment: Not working with ssh 6.9p1: Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.

Comment: note also, if you use this verbatim, replacing $KEY with your actual key, you'll leak it through your shell's history. The key should really come from stdin, not from shell.

Comment: This only gives me: 
```@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0660 for '/dev/stdin' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
Load key "/dev/stdin": bad permissions
Permission denied (publickey).```

Comment: will work via `fifo`, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/235392/78029

Comment: `$KEY` must be quoted: `echo "$KEY"`

Answer (score 2):

Passing cryptokey as a string is not advisable but for the sake of the question, I would say I came across the same situation where I need to pass key as a string in a script. I could use key stored in  a file too but the nature of the script is to make it very flexible, containing everything in itself was a requirement. so I used to assign variable and pass it and echo it as follows :

```
#!/bin/bash
KEY="${ YOUR SSH KEY HERE INSIDE }"
echo "${KEY}" | ssh -q -i /dev/stdin username@IP 'hostnamectl'
exit 0
```

Notes: 
 `-q` suppress all warnings

By the way , the catch here in above script, since we are using echo it will print the ssh key which is again not recommended , to hide that you can use grep to grep some anything which will not be printed for sure but still `stdin` will have the value from the echo. So the final cmd can be modified as follows :

```
#!/bin/bash
KEY="${ YOUR SSH KEY HERE INSIDE }"
echo "${KEY}" | grep -qw "less" | ssh -q -i /dev/stdin username@IP 'hostnamectl'
exit 0
```

This worked for me.

Comment: It is not advisable to keep it plaintext.

But,

`sops --decrypt some-key.enc.pem | ssh ...` is very much feasible

Where the key is encrypted all the time

https://github.com/getsops/sops

Answer (score 2):

I was looking at the same problem. Adding private key content to `ssh`  command via stdin did not work for me. I found out that its possible to add the private key file contents to `ssh-agent` using the command `ssh-add`. This will let you `ssh` into the remote host without explicitly specifying the identity file. My particular usecase was that I didn't want to store the SSH key in cleartext on my machine and was dynamically getting it from a secrets vault. This answer is mostly a collection of other answers on StackOverflow.

> ssh-agent is a program to hold private keys used for public key
> authentication.  Through use of environment variables the agent can
> be located and automatically used for authentication when logging
> in to other machines using ssh

[Source](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ssh-agent.1.html)

This is what I have done.
First start the `ssh-agent`.
You can start it from your terminal by simply executing `ssh-agent`.
**OPTIONAL:** If you'd like to make sure `ssh-agent` is running on every login, you can add something like the following to your shell config.
This is what I have added to my `~/.bashrc`  file.

```
# set SSH_AUTH_SOCK env var to a fixed value
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=~/.ssh/ssh-agent.sock

# test whether $SSH_AUTH_SOCK is valid
ssh-add -l 2>/dev/null >/dev/null

# if not valid, then start ssh-agent using $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
[ $? -ge 2 ] && ssh-agent -a "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" >/dev/null
```

[Source](https://serverfault.com/questions/832615/how-ssh-agent-process-is-increasing-on-every-login)
(This particular snippet also makes sure new ssh-agent processes are not getting created when there's one already running.)

Now you have the `ssh-agent` running.
Since we're interested in loading SSH key as a string, I'll assume a scenario where private key contents has already been loaded in to a variable, `$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY`.

I can now add this Key contents to the `ssh-agent` by executing the following command.

```
ssh-add - <<< "${SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}"
```

This can just be added to the bashrc file as well.
You can confirm that your key has been added by listing all keys by executing `ssh-agent -l`. Aaand you're done now.

Try connecting to the remote host and you don't need a private key file.

```
ssh username@hostname
```

This does come with extra security risks. These are some I could think of:

1. Adding the private key to the ssh-agent will let any process on the machine access the key to authenticate remote hosts without explicitly providing any information.
2. Since the goal is to load Private key as a string, it will either be stored in a variable or the contents embedded directly in the command. This might make the key available in command history, the shell variable and other places.