# Add SSH key from variable

Tags: bash, ssh, ssh-keys

I have a bash script inside a Docker container that needs to access remote server via ssh. I have SSH key inside a variable. How can I add it to SSH?

Comment: How did the key get in the variable in the first place? You might want to skip that step and have `ssh-add` read directly from the original file.

Comment: In my particular case SSH key is a GitLab secret variable.

Comment: It's only because it's not available in a file that we need to load it from a variable. Hence this question.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
ssh-add - <<< "${SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}"
```

Comment: Or since it is bash `ssh-add - <<<"${SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}"` and use a *herestring*.

Comment: Is it faster? And why `<<<`? What about `ssh-add - < "${SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}"`?

Comment: Well, the variable `"${SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}"` holds the value. You need it as input on `stdin` for `ssh-add`. As a convenience feature bash has both a *heredoc* and *herestring*. You can use the *herestring` `<<<` to make the variable data in `"${SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}"` appear as input on `stdin` for `ssh-add` with `ssh-add - <<<"${SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}"`. It is faster in that no additional *subshells* are generated. You have 3 generated with `echo key | ssh-add -` (1-for `echo`, 1-for the pipe `|` and 1-for ssh-add). (note: you may or may not need the `'-'` after `ssh-add`, but I suspect you do.)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Yes you need the '-' or ssh-add will look for the key in $HOME/.ssh

Comment: This solution is not working with Paker provisioner `shell` and returning the error: `Syntax error: redirection unexpected`

This is because here strings like <<< "$token" are not supported by POSIX /bin/sh

Use the solution from GitLab provided by @Dieter Casier

Comment: If you are trying this in GitHub Actions, you need to do `eval $(ssh-agent -s) && ssh-add - <<< '${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}'`.

Comment: Not working in Bash 5: `Error loading key "(stdin)": invalid format`

Answer (score 23):

If you are using Gitlab CI/CD and you want to use a variable as an SSH key you can do the following:

- Add your variable in `Settings` -> `CI/CD` -> `Variables`
- Use that variable in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

  `- echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add - > /dev/null`

[Gitlab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/)

Answer (score 6):

Also, you can use:

`echo "${SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}" | ssh-add -` 

or
`ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")`

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me `echo "${SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}" | ssh-add - `