# How can I add git credentials in github workflow

Tags: git, github, automation, continuous-deployment

**Question:**

How can I add git credentials in the `GitHub` workflow?

**nodejs.yml**

```
name: Node CI

on:
  push:
    branches: 
      - master
      - gh-pages 

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [8.x, 10.x]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
    - name: npm run deploy
      run: |
        npm install
        npm run deploy  
      env:
        CI: t
```

Comment: What CI is this? Travis CI?

Comment: github workflow and actions

Comment: Interested parties may find more comprehensive and a greater variety of solutions under this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57612428/cloning-private-github-repository-within-organisation-in-actions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it like this:

**nodejs.yml**

```
name: Node CI

on:
  push:
    branches: 
      - master

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [8.x]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1

    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}

    - uses: fusion-engineering/setup-git-credentials@v2
      with:
        credentials: ${{secrets.GIT_CREDENTIAL}}

    - name: npm run deploy
      run: |
        export GIT_USER=${{secrets.GIT_USER}}
        git config --global user.name "$GIT_USER"
        git config --global user.email "hi@pushe.co"
        npm install
        npm run deploy  
      env:
        CI: true
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature for it, check out [github secrets](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/creating-and-using-encrypted-secrets).