# Install private repository from a private repository of the same organization

Tags: git, github, workflow, github-actions

I have two private repositories in the same organization, say repository A and B, both of which are python packages. I have a "GitHub Actions workflow" to test repository B for each PR. However, repository B depends on repository A, so I would need to install it.
I tried following [this GitHub document](https://help.github.com/en/packages/using-github-packages-with-your-projects-ecosystem/using-github-packages-with-github-actions#installing-a-package-using-an-action), however, it specifically states

`GITHUB_TOKEN cannot install packages from any private repository besides the repository where the action runs.`

How do I go about implementing this installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That just means, that you cannot use the predefined `GITHUB_TOKEN`. Create a personal access token (PAT) with `read:packages` scope and add it as a secret to your repository.

> If you need a token that requires permissions that aren't available in the GITHUB_TOKEN, you can create a personal access token and set it as a secret in your repository:
>
> 1. Use or create a token with the appropriate permissions for that repository. For more information, see "[Creating a personal access token](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token)".
> 2. Add the token as a secret in your workflow's repository, and refer to it using the ${{ secrets.SECRET_NAME }} syntax. For more information, see "[Creating and using encrypted secrets](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/creating-and-using-encrypted-secrets)".

Source: https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/authentication-in-a-workflow#permissions-for-the-github_token

Comment: Forgot to answer my own question, indeed this is the only possible way to do it. Github recommends in the docs to have a "bot" user which can be used to do just this.

Comment: So the solution is to use my personal credentials, even when other users in my organization run the workflow?  I don't like that, and our corporate security dept. wouldn't like the "bot user" approach since you lose the ability to audit who really did something.

Comment: @KellyDenehy It's not optimal but at least it's read-only access only to packages, so nothing can't be changed.

Comment: This answer suggests using ssh "GitHub deploy" keys, which avoids the personal PAT issue. Please correct me if that doesn't work, I haven't tried it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70283191/5156887