# Access another repo in organization in github action

Tags: github-actions, git-clone

I have a github action yml file that runs in a repo in an organization, in this file I need information that is in another repo inside the same organization. How can I clone this repo inside the yml file, so I can access the information there?
I have tried

```
- name: Checkout configs
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
      with:

        repository: org/configs
        token: ${{ secrets.GH_PAT }} 
        path: configs
```

Im not sure if this `secrets.GH_PAT` need to be created or if this is something stored in the org or repo.
The error I get that it cant find the token.
And if I change the token to: `token: ${{ secrets.GH_PAT || github.token }}`  it cant find the repo.

Comment: you should refer to the linked doc https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/creating-and-using-encrypted-secrets about how to creating the token and how to configure the token in the repo settings

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cloning private github repository within organisation in actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57612428/cloning-private-github-repository-within-organisation-in-actions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was that a admin needed to create a token in the org.

```
- name: Checkout configs
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
      with:
        repository: org/configs
        token: ${{ secrets.TOKEN_CREATED_BY_ADMIN }}
        path: configs
        ref: master
```

Answer (score 0):

Here missing the branch name ref.

- name: Checkout configs
  uses: actions/checkout@v3
  with:

  ```
    repository: org/configs
    ref: <branch name>
    token: ${{ secrets.GH_PAT }} 
    path: configs
  ```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).