# Github actions/checkout@v3 - checkout another repo from the same Organization does not work

Tags: github-actions, git-checkout

I have two repos `A` and `B` in the same organization on our self-hosted Github enterprise instance. Repo `B` is a dependency for the code in repo `A`, so I want to create a workflow in repo `A`, where both repos are checked out.

Here is the workflow I tried so far:

- create a SSH-key with git-bash:

  1. `ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "myemail@company.com"`
  2. no passphrase
  3. This creates two files one `.pub` for the public key and one for the private key
- In Repo `B` go to Settings->deploy keys->add deploy key and copy the contents of the public key as the value- In Repo `A` go to Settings->Secrets and variables->Actions->New Repository Secret and copy the content of the private key as value
- Test the following workflow yaml
- 

```
name: My Workflow

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build-and-push-image:
    name: test
    runs-on: [ self-hosted, fast]

    steps:
      - name: Check out repo A
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          path: path_to_A

      - name: Check out repo A
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          repository: myorg/b
          path: path_to_B
          ssh-key: ${{ secrets.PRIVATE_KEY_B }}

      - name: debug # just to debug
        run: find .
```

Unfortunately this does not work and I get the following errors:

> No ECDSA host key is known for github.company.com and you have requested strict checking.
> Host key verification failed.
> Error: fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

I am not sure what the issue is here. I have also already tried to set the private key for the ssh agent as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70283191/7745011), but also without success. Any pointers would be much appreciated!

**Edit**
Just to add some information, the error only appears while checking out repo `B`. Checkout for repo `A` works flawlessly. I am actually not sure, why there should be different access rights between the two repos.

Comment: Did you try using a `PAT` instead of the `ssh-key`? (I agree it should work for both, but this is just to check, as the action README gives an example with a PAT [here](https://github.com/actions/checkout#checkout-multiple-repos-private)).

Comment: @GuiFalourd I did not so far, but honestly I don't want to use a PAT, since the new ones (which can be restricted to a single repo) are not available in our Enterprise version and the classic one would allow access to all of the repos and organizations I have access to.

Comment: I might however test out a PAT just to know if it would work.

Comment: @GuiFalourd I finally got around to test with a PAT and this works nicely. As mentioned I would really like to avoid using a PAT

Comment: Nice! I would suggest opening an ISSUE to the repository `actions/checkout` explaining what you want to achieve, because it doesn't seem to me that this is currently supported for ssh-key. Only for PAT.

Comment: Already done :)

Comment: Just saw it [here](https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/1382) :D