# Repository not found error while using actions/checkout@v4 to clone a private repo on a self-hosted runner

Tags: github-actions

I tried to use actions/checkout@v4 to checkout my private repo on my self-hosted runner but I got this error:

```
ERROR: Repository not found.
Error: The process bin/git failed with exit code 128
...Please ensure that the correct permissions exist...
```

Here's my workflow:

```yaml
name: 'some job'

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  some-job:
    runs-on: ['self-hosted']
    steps:
      - name: 'Checkout Service'
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          repository: "some-name/test"
          path: test
          token: "<here is my token>"
          ref: main
```

What I considered:

The self hosted runner was invoked. The branch `main` exists. The token is inserted correctly. The personal access token (PAT) was created with my GitHub account in the developer settings. I verified the token with the git CLI. The token has the permissions to checkout my private repo. It may have to do with my self-hosted runner? Is there anything else I need to consider? I also tried to checkout a public repository which works as expected to rule out other problems.

Comment: Have you considered using deploy keys instead? See the chosen answer and links in this question: [Cloning private github repository within organisation in actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57612428/cloning-private-github-repository-within-organisation-in-actions).

Comment: Are you able to clone the repo directly on your self-hosted runner machine via CLI, same as you did on your local machine?

Comment: @ rffontenelle It works with deploy keys. Thx. Why it isn't working with PAT dunno

Comment: @Azeem
Yes from my self-hosted runner it works also with git-cli and PAT. Why the checkout action can't handle the PAT correctly remains unknown to me

Comment: What is the command that you use to clone it there? Try that in a run section instead of actions/checkout. See if that works.