# Use SSH KEY from ENV Var

Tags: ruby, git

I need to run some git commands from a ruby on rails application. I have the ssh private key (password protected) stored in an env var. How can I run git commands using the ssh keys from the env var without dumping it on the filesystem?

Comment: Git literally just runs ssh. (This isn't true of jgit or Go-git so be sure you're using the C version here before you use the rest of this comment.) The ssh command literally *only* reads the keys from either an agent or from the file system, so you will *have to* load the keys into one of these two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging I found a solution using openssl:

`echo "#{private_key}" | openssl rsa -passin pass:$PRIVATE_KEY_PASSPHRASE | ssh-add -`

Comment: Well done. That should work indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your key does not have passphrase, you can try [adding it to an ssh-agent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46253163/6309) (that you can [start automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72653643/6309)):

```
ssh-add - <<< "${SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}"
```

With passphrase, [you would need to enter it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/90869/7490) somehow, which is not practical in your case.

The alternative is indeed to dump it to a file, but it can be a [temp file which will be cleaned up](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/687345/7490).

In that case, set `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` to '`ssh -i /tmp/TempFileGenerated`', and you git commands (clone/push/pull/...) will use that for any SSH URL.